# Jasmine Cannot find the router object, so the spyOn function essentially breaks

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test my router in Karma Jasmine. I'm very new to this language, so it may be a basic error, but I can't get it to work. It posts an error stating that it "could not find an object to spy upon for navigate()". Below is my code.

I considered moving its location around the testbed and that has not changed the outcome. I've made the router testbed injection into an object opposed to service because it references that it's looking for an object within the error. I have also put console.logs throughout my code at different periods and it always returns as undefined. I'm confused about what I'm doing wrong and any insights/ideas would be greatly appreciated!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rR8rS.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4s2B.png)

Comment: If in the future you add code examples as code blocks in your question, it is much easier to read and you are more likely to get an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In the providers array of the testing module, you provide for `Router` the value `trueRouter`. But `trueRouter` was never instantiated, so it is undefined. You should rather create a spy object and provide this like the following:

```
let router: SpyObj<Router>;

... in the beforeEach ...
router = createSpyObj('Router', ['navigate']);

... in the Testbed providers array ...
{ provide: Router, useValue: router }
...

... in the test: ...
expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalled();
```